# Cocoapods fails to lint with swift 3.0 errors even though project is swift 2.3

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a private pod, and I am trying to do a `pod repo push` but its rejecting it because of errors that could only happen in `Swift3.0` e.g `@noescape is the default and is deprecated`. I use --allow-warnings but there are also errors beside this warning, this is just the most obvious `Swift3.0` error.

The project itself is in `Swift2.3`, I have the legacy flag setup in all targets, not to mention I have pushed a new spec just a few days ago and I am unaware what could have changed. The project builds fine in `Xcode`.

If its relevant, the pod that happens to error out is the `Result` one, but I am sure it could be any of them.

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm not even using swift for my library.............

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am guessing more people might hit this, cause if you call `pod spec lint` instead of `push` straight away `Cocoapods` will point you to the correct answer:

`` The validator for Swift projects uses Swift 3.0 by default, if you are using a different version of swift you can use a `.swift-version` file to set the version for your Pod. For example to use Swift 2.3, run: 
    `echo "2.3" > .swift-version`. ``

Comment: More specifically you have to create a file called .swift-version in which you need to add the version. Run `xcrun swift -version` in terminal to know your swift version. Then you need to run `echo "your.swift.version" > .swift-version`. Your issue will be solved :-)